# Как заменить символы в таблице MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, база-данных

Подскажите, как заменить символы в таблице БД MS SQL. 
Есть столбец типа `ntext`, в котором нужно найти все буквы "а" и заменить на "б".

И чтоб замена производилась в кодировке UTF-8...

Answer (score 4):

Если версия поддерживает тип varchar(max):

```
update t 
set f = replace(cast(f as nvarchar(max)), N'а', N'б')
```

Comment: И чтоб замена производилась в кодировке UTF-8... как?

Comment: Так попробуйте:
update t 
set f = replace(cast(f as nvarchar(max)),N'а',N'б')

Comment: Символы "а" входящие в состав слов заменяться будут? Что то меняет всю запись в ячейке с кириллицей на ??????? ???? ?????.... Кодировка поля с текстом в таблице SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Символы заменяться будут.
А коллацию нужно сделать киррилическую. Latin1 не содержит кириллицы, оттого вы видите ??????? ???? ?????.
Или использовать юникод. Вот тест:
------
declare @t table(f ntext, f2 ntext);
insert into @t values(N'ааааааnnааааааааmmm','ааааааnnааааааааmmm');
update @t 
set f = replace(cast(f as nvarchar(max)),N'а',N'б'),
f2 = replace(cast(f2 as nvarchar(max)),N'а',N'б');
select * from @t 
-----
Сравните 2 столбца

Comment: А как сделать чтобы данный запрос заменял символы в кодировке SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

 update t set f = replace(cast(f as varchar(max)),'а','б') 

просто кодировку в таблице менять нельзя. Но нужно чтоб кириллица в таблицу записывалась корректно

Comment: Я же вам дал пример:
insert into @t values(N'ааааааnnааааааааmmm','ааааааnnааааааааmmm');
Запись в первый столбец выполняется корректно.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, "а", "б")
```

Comment: Две ошибки:
1. REPLACE не работает для типа ntext.
2. "a" --> 'a'